# Как узнать, какой фрагмент сейчас на экране?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, eventbus

Пробовал так:

```
    private Fragment currentFragment;

        @Subscribe
            public void changeFragment(EChangeFragment event){
                Fragment fragment = event.getFragment();
                if(fragment.equals(currentFragment)) {
                    Log.d("mytag", "MainPresenter.changeFragment() already that fragment");
                    return;
                }
                currentFragment = fragment;
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if(event.isAddToBackStack()) fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            setNewFragment(fragment);
            hideNavigationMenu(event.isHideMenu());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

Но это не помогает! В `if` мы никогда не заходим.

Пробовал и такой способ:

```
@Subscribe
    public void changeFragment(EChangeFragment event){
        Fragment fragment = event.getFragment();
        if(fragment.equals(getCurrentFragment())) {
            Log.d("mytag", "MainPresenter.changeFragment() already that fragment");
            return;
        }
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if(event.isAddToBackStack()) fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        setNewFragment(fragment);
        hideNavigationMenu(event.isHideMenu());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private Fragment getCurrentFragment(){
       return fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content);
    }
```

Тоже не помогает. Мне надо проверять текущий фрагмент на экране, чтобы при клике на меню открывался другой фрагмент, однако если новый же фрагмент- тот, который на экране, ничего не делать

**UPD:**

Как отправляется эвент с изменением фрагмента:

```
private void openIntroducingFragment(){
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentFullscreen();
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new EChangeFragment(new IntroducingFragment(), DONT_ADD_TO_BACKSTACK,
                HIDE_TOOLBAR, HIDE_MENU));
    }
```

**EChangeEvent.java**

```
public EChangeFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, boolean deprecated, boolean hideMenu){
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.addToBackStack = addToBackStack;
    this.hideMenu = hideMenu;
}
```

Comment: Можно сохранять текущий фрагмент в поле `currentFragment` в активити. А чтобы проверить какой конкретно фрагмент в `currentFragment`, можно проверить на `instanceof`.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov т.е. мне через множество if (или swith-case) надо пролистываться через все фрагменты? Именно такого пути я и избегал :)

Comment: Так в любом случае нужно будет if пробегаться, а как еще определить какой конкретно фрагмент из множества сейчас на экране?

Answer (score 1):

На экране может находиться несколько фрагментов, поэтому нативного метода узнать фрагмент существует несколько:

- По тэгу (который передаётся в момент транзакции с фрагментом)
- По resource id, к которому привязан фрагмент

Таким образом, вы сами должны обеспокоиться о том, чтобы хранить "актуальный" фрагмент отдельно

Вообще, стоит подумать об архитектуре, раз такое приходится делать:)

Comment: Какой правильный, с точки зрения архитектуры, тут должен быть подход?

Comment: Ну раз у вас фрагмент с кнопкой, значит, вы можете перенести обработку нажатия на неё в фрагмент, где кнопка находится